# Web Service checking that DB is available

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I need to create an ASP.NET web service that simply returns an information telling if a database is available or down when it's consumed.

So I would like to know if I can set a task that is executed inside the web service method on a regular basis to check the connection to the database and return the result via a URL.

Comment: It is possible, but a web service is not really the appropriate solution. Why not a scheduled task that runs a console app?

Comment: Why do you need a web service? Is the database in a different server and you want to check connection via web application from outside?

Comment: You can but you shouldn't

Comment: @Platus, you need to tell us more about for what you intend to use that webservice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot. Well, you *could*, but you **really** should **not**. A webservice is *on demand*. If it's called, it does work. If it's not called, it's not running.

You may have been thinking of a *windows* service. *That* is something that is always running and can do stuff in the background.

(A windows service may have an additional web frontend to see it's data. Or any other way to visualize it's data points, for example another database.)

Comment: I have seen people do this, so it is possible. But highly questionable.

Comment: @Liam I have seen people doing it. It's a failure either waiting to happen, or happening while you watch. You flinch. Like watching somebody hammering in a screw.

Comment: Totally agree it's just the first sentence *No you cannot* I'd argue isn't **strictly** true.

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged c# and asp so you are using Sql server database, 
this query gives you databases that exists on your sql server instance:

```
  select * from master.dbo.sysdatabases
```

result contains name and some extra information, name gives you database names, mode column have a int value indicates that database is in creating mode or created mode, status column that contains a int value(power of 2)

If you would like to see if database is offline or not, you can see status value if it is 512 your database is offline, for 1024 it is in read only mode

for your service you can use web api, web method or wcf, it is depend on you

---

If you use hangfire, quartz or any other scheduler you can set a background job on your server to check your database status

"return the result via a URL" I can not understand this, but if you want to notify users about database you can use push notification on your background job

Comment: While correct, this has nothing to do with the actual question.

Comment: I sent my answer before it complete :)) sorry